# Expression is not evaluated in aura iteration block

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-experience

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.overDueTasks}" var="task">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="{!task.Id}" label=" " change="{!c.addTaskToList}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:DFActivityCardCmp taskId="{!task.Id}" subject="{!task.Subject}" owner="{!task.Owner.Name}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller method**

```
addTaskToList:function(component, event, helper) {
      var sourceCheckbox = event.getSource();
      console.log(sourceCheckbox.getLocalId());
}
```

`sourceCheckbox.getLocalId()` prints `{!task.Id}` in console.
What is the problem with my code?

Comment: @Praveen The linked question does not appear to answer this question's intent.

Comment: @sfdcfox `aura:id` cannot be bounded to an aura:expression and that's the reason why `sourceCheckbox.getLocalId()` returns `{!task.Id}`. So I believe it should be closed. If I'm wrong i'll retract it.

Comment: @Praveen Never mind, you're right. It's too presumptions of me to read too much into the question. It's late and I should probably go to bed.

Comment: Nilesh-- if you want to go with binding dynamic Id values, the linked question should suit you just fine. However, you should think about what you're trying to do. I feel you might be trying to use the wrong tool for whatever purpose you have in mind. `aura:id` is meant to help you find values the same way that HTML's name attribute works (e.g. getElementsByName). It believe it'd be more appropriate to use `text` instead, since you're trying to figure out which task you want to move.